# RavenDB multi map

Tags: ravendb, multimap

I have a DB containing many tables, and every table has different properties, and 
I want to achive the following:

Create and index on **all** of the properties (from every table).

The problem is that I don't have a class for every table for I have used dynamic classes to insert them to the DB.

So how can I create an index that given a string will return all documents that one of their properties contains that string?

Another problem needed to be solved is that in future Tables insertion I can add the new table to the index I explained above.

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

David,
You don't have **tables** in RavenDB, but that aside, you can just define an index over the entire data set, like this:

```
     from doc in docs select new { doc.Name }
```

Which will define an index over all types, allowing you to query over all the documents' names.